# Can you share ownership of a utility?

Tags: osiris-new-dawn

In multiplayer, when you build (for example) a depository, it is claimed as your own.  Unfortunately, when you are part of a colony (a team basically), it appears that utilities like this cannot be accessed by teammates.  Other structures such as the inflatable dome says that the colony owns them, and allows all players of that colony to access it.

Is it possible to get utilities to be owned by the colony like an inflatable dome? It's a bit frustrating having to open up my depository just to get one item out for a teammate to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are able to use the multi-tool to share buildings and utilities with the colony.

Edit: Example of setting the depository to shared: Take out the multi tool, aim it at the depository (in close proximity). It shows the options of what you can do, one of which is <kbd>N</kbd> "Make Public To Colony." Select that, and it is shared with everyone in the colony.